# Фоновое проигрывание музыки в форме Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, аудио

Как можно реализовать проигрывание музыки в форме в Delphi? Музыка должна играть фоном(не аудио плеер), формат wav/mp3

Comment: Формат музыки укажите в вопросе плиз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая простая реалзизация именно `MediaPlayer` (Tool Panel - System - TMediaPlayer). Располагаете на форме компонент, делаете ему `Visible:=false`, настраиваете и вуаля. Более сложное решение использовать сторонние библиотеки.